# Getting script error everytime my PC starts, How can i stop it?

Tags: windows-7

Every time i start up my PC i get this error message which is really frustrating. I can't figure out why its happening or how to stop it from happening. I'm running Windows 7.

[image]

I've tried to google for the error message but didn't seem to return much relevance.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you find the file referenced, open it in notepad and tell us what the first couple of lines say?

Comment: Here is the first few lines: http://pastebin.com/WvWkmMnF

Comment: You should be aware that this type of behavior indicates you have a malware infection

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound. It's a random-named file ending with `.vbe` (which is just an encoded version of a Visual Basic Script file) that started automatically. Open `msconfig` and check if you see anything related in the startup entries. Putting the whole code on pastebin may shed some more light too.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key combo or just press start and select Run.

And enter msconfig and delete all those autostart entries you dont need and slow down PC and its start time.

You should find the program which shows this in there.

Comment: and definitelly run some malware scan like superantispyware, because there may be more infection points to clean.

Answer (score -2):

Use Virustotal on the program and also install any anti-virus and run a malware scan and delete it.
This will speed up your PC a bit and also delete any viruses.